# Can I use appodeal with admob?

Tags: mobile, admob

I'm currently using admob but there is still some space left in my app so I was thinking of using appodeal with admob. Not using the mediation method but more like admob banners at the bottom and appodeal banners on the top. Can I do that?
Also, is it necessary to link appodeal with admob? I'm trying to link but the admob reporting isn't enabled and I can't enable it for some reason and I can't syn both accounts.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Appodeal with my AdMob account, as far as I know AdMob did some changes and the guys from Appodeal have updated their plugin. Try to install its last version, by the way their support team is very helpful and responds rather quickly. To my mind, there isn't much sense in using Appodeal apart from AdMob, because linking up accounts together you'll get access to all platforms they support (including AdMob) and will get max possible revenue. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But  I have heard that you can't use 2 banners in one activity :/ It's admob policy. Is this true? :/

Comment: btw I do have latest plugin installed I will contact their support team

Comment: Yeah, you're right, there is a limitation with 2 banners in one activity. But in fact, if that activity contains something like a long scroll view, 2 banners can be shown while the user scrolls.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - you can and should use Appodeal and sync your Admob account. Appodeal works best if you have your Admob account integrated according to the instructions they provide.

The plug-in to sync Appodeal with Admob is updated and monitored constantly and [per the date of this thread] was most recently updated on September 7th 2015 to v3.4.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Appodeal for 5 months. It was great when AdMob worked together with all networks, but still it's quite easy to integrate it with the help of plugin. Thanks for update, everything works fine! Very impressed with your support team, great job guys, keep on going!

Comment: Have you seen a difference in the app size before and after including their Framework? Because the framework bundle is around 500mb, was wondering if it will not increase too much my 14mb app :/